# Problems with model2-names.bst

Tags: bibliographies

I am using model2-names.bst which is built-in with the journal that I am submitting my article to. However, for some reason, the journal name and volume number are attached and not separated by a comma (,) in the output after using PDFLaTeX.

An example: P. F. Goldsmith, Molecular Depletion and Thermal Balance in Dark Cloud Cores, ApJ557 (2001) 736–746. doi:10.1086/322255.

In the above example, the ApJ (journal) and 557 (volume number) are attached and not separate.

The entry for this reference in the bibliography file is:

```
@ARTICLE{Gold01,
   author = {{Goldsmith}, P.~F.},
    title = "{Molecular Depletion and Thermal Balance in Dark Cloud Cores}",
  journal = {\apj},
 keywords = {ISM: Clouds, ISM: Globules, ISM: Molecules, Molecular Processes},
     year = 2001,
    month = aug,
   volume = 557,
    pages = {736-746},
      doi = {10.1086/322255},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001ApJ...557..736G},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

The related bibitem for the entry above in the .bbl is:

```
\bibitem{Gold01}
P.~F. {Goldsmith}, {Molecular Depletion and Thermal Balance in Dark Cloud
  Cores}, \apj 557 (2001) 736--746.
\newblock \href {http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/322255}{\path{doi:10.1086/322255}}.
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the bib entry in question. Do also indicate if you use any bibliography-related packages. Without this information, any answer is going to be no more than a stab in the dark.

Comment: @Mico - I attached the output in the resulting .bbl file for the above example from the output PDF document. I am not using any external bibliography software.

Comment: It would still be helpful if you showed the bib entry. The `\bibitem` suggests that there might be a bug in the definition of the `\apj` macro. However, without the source code it's not possible to test this hypothesis.

Comment: There is an issue with the \apj macro - I have had to issue the command:      \newcommand{\apj}{ApJ} in the original .tex file

Comment: So the problem isn't with the `model2-names` bibliography style but with your definition of the `\apj` macro. You mention that you "had to" define it via `\newcommand{\apj}{ApJ}`; is there a reason why you couldn't define it via `\newcommand{\apj}{ApJ }`?

Comment: What is the issue with such macros as \apj defined in the .bib file like above? I can never get my "bibtex"-ing of the file to accept the macro "as is".

Comment: I've posted an answer that addresses your questions and, actually, proposes an even better solution than redefining the `\apj` macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two strategies:

1. typing `journal={\apj{}}`, or
2. defining a string `apj` and type `journal=apj`

I'd prefer the latter.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Gold01,
   author = {Goldsmith, P. F.},
    title = {Molecular Depletion and Thermal Balance in Dark Cloud Cores},
  journal = {\apj{}},
 keywords = {ISM: Clouds, ISM: Globules, ISM: Molecules, Molecular Processes},
     year = 2001,
    month = aug,
   volume = 557,
    pages = {736-746},
      doi = {10.1086/322255},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001ApJ...557..736G},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
@STRING{
  apj={ApJ}
}
@ARTICLE{Gold0X,
   author = {Goldsmith, P. F.},
    title = {Molecular Depletion and Thermal Balance in Dark Cloud Cores},
  journal = apj,
 keywords = {ISM: Clouds, ISM: Globules, ISM: Molecules, Molecular Processes},
     year = 2001,
    month = aug,
   volume = 557,
    pages = {736-746},
      doi = {10.1086/322255},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001ApJ...557..736G},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\apj}{ApJ}
\begin{document}
\cite{Gold01}

\cite{Gold0X}

\bibliographystyle{model2-names}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used to use the latter method all the time. I manoeuvred from this as I began to produce .bib files and favoured an automated approach as opposed to manually altering all the bibtex-style references from Google Scholar containing the various macros pertaining to the journal names, e.g. \apj, \mnras, etc.

Comment: @stars83clouds If I export the `.bib` data from Google Scholar, I get `journal={The Astrophysical Journal},` so you have to alter it anyway. The `@STRING` entries can go in a different `.bib` file and you can choose, for example, between full and abbreviated. If you prefer to use TeX macros, it's not more difficult to add `{}` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the bibliography style, but with the way you've defined the macro `\apj`: `\newcommand{\apj}{ApJ}`.

As you probably know, TeX ignores spaces after macros whose names contain only letters, e.g., `\apj`. Thus, if you want a space to show up between the abbreviated journal name and the volume number, you need to either change the macro's definition to `\newcommand{\apj}{ApJ }` or change the `journal` field to `journal = {\apj\ },`.

Actually, there's a third -- and even better -- solution, which doesn't use a macro at all:

- At the start of the bib file, set up the following string constant definition:

  ```
  @string{ apj = "ApJ" }
  ```
- Then, set the `journal` field to

  ```
  journal = apj,
  ```

That way, you'll get a space if a space is called for, and no space if it's not -- say, because in some other bibliography style the journal name is followed by a comma.